# How to change the ProcessorId

Tags: cmd

I want to change my pc's ProcessorId. We can get ProcessorId by using "wmic cpu get ProcessorId" in cmd.

It show's
ProcessorId
BFEBFBFF000306D4

I want to change this ProcessorId BFEBFBFF000306D4 into a different id.

If there is any way to change the ProcessorId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Win32_Processor class documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373(v=vs.85).aspx), `ProcessorId` property is **read-only**:

> ProcessorId
>
> Data type: string 
> Access type: **Read-only** 
> Qualifiers:
>   [MappingStrings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393650(v=vs.85).aspx) ("SMBIOS|Type 4|Processor Information|Processor
>   ID")
>
> Processor information that describes the processor features. For an
>   x86 class CPU, the field format depends on the processor support of
>   the `CPUID` instruction. If the instruction is supported, the property
>   contains 2 (two) *DWORD* formatted values.  
> The first is an
>   offset of `08h-0Bh`, which is the EAX value that a `CPUID` instruction
>   returns with input EAX set to 1. The second is an offset of `0Ch-0Fh`,
>   which is the EDX value that the instruction returns. Only the first
>   two bytes of the property are significant and contain the contents of
>   the DX register at CPU reset—all others are set to 0 (zero), and the
>   contents are in *DWORD* format.
>
> This value comes from the Processor ID member of the Processor
>   Information structure in the SMBIOS information.